# 'attributes' for login button in login form

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-theming, drupal-templates

I need to theme the login form. I need additional css classes and  tabindex for the form elements.

Now I have a problem with these both for the login button.

In template.php I use 'attributes' for that. For e.g. the password field it works perfect with this code:

```
$form['pass']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'input-sm form-control';
$form['pass']['#attributes']['tabindex'][] = '2';
```

When I use this for the button - nothing is rendered in html:

```
$form['op']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'test-button';
$form['op']['#attributes']['tabindex'][] = '3';
```

'op' is the name of the login button which I can see in html output.

How can I get the 'class' and 'tabindex' to the login button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the button you should use **`$form['#submit']`**.

In any case you can use **[hook_form_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7)** and **[devel](https://drupal.org/project/devel)**'s `dpm($form)` to get the form data. A generic example:

```
function MYTHEME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  dpm($form);
}
```

The submit button may be accessed like this for a common Drupal theme (structure taken from the dpm() function):

```
$form['actions']['submit']['#attributes']['tabindex'][] = "2";
```

One important thing here is to **be careful because you may override the form again** later on your theme... In this case look for the very last hook and apply changes there.

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work. I tried

$form['#submit']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'test-button';

and

$form['submit']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'test-button';

Comment: Sorry, the bad was on my side. copy&paste wants to be learned ;-). Your code works.

Thank you very much!